Cache clean-up on Publishing:End:Remote with multiple CMs
Our Sitecore CM (PAAS hosting) handles a lot of traffic. We plan to cater to this traffic with multiple web apps in Azure.
I am unable to figure out the following:
On the Publish:End:Remote event, Sitecore purges the cache. In my case, we have multiple CMs. So how will it purge the cache on all instances?
Or should we write code to override the default functionality and provide all the arguments programmatically?

Remote publish end event will be able to clear the cache on all the CM servers. You need to make sure the scalability setting for multiple CM servers are set properly.
When configuring multiple CM server, only one CM instance will be responsible for publishing. In order to configure the same, you need to provide following configuration on CM servers.

Assign each CM server, a instance name based on the machine name plus the IIS server name. You must ensure that each CM instance has a unique name.

<setting name="InstanceName">
  <patch:attribute name="value"><your unique CM instance name> 
   </patch:attribute>
</setting>


Only one CM instance can perform publishing, and you must ensure that each CM instance points to the publishing CM instance.

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
    <patch:attribute name="value"><your publishing CM instance name> 
    </patch:attribute>
</setting>

Note: On publishing instance server, above setting Publishing.PublishingInstance should be empty.
You can find more details for the same here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/platform-administration-and-architecture/configure-multiple-content-management-instances.html
Hope this helps!!!
